# Why am I limited to ~10-20 usb devices?

Tags: linux, centos, usb

I am trying to hook up 27 USB device to an Intel NUC running CentOS 7 but no matter what I do the system can never see more than 20.  I have tried multiple models of NUCs and even tried adding an extra mPCIe USB controller card to one, I tried a 1U server with an Intel Xeon and an extra PCIe USB controller card, and even tried a Mac Mini.  The Mac Mini was able to recognize the most devices at 20 but this is still shy of what we need.  The extra USB controller cards made no difference in the number of devices the system recognized.  The 27 devices are spread across 3 powered 10 port hubs.  Does anyone know why the systems would not be able to see all of the USB devices since even with the hubs it is still way under the 127 USB spec limit?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: does `lsusb -t` show all the devices, or can you see where the missing ones should be? Are all the devices the same, eg serial port?

Comment: I just ran `lsusb -t` and, no, the devices are no showing.  I can tell where they should be but they are not there.  And, yes, all the devices are the same.

Comment: Perhaps the total isochronous bandwidth needed for the devices exceeds that available at the host. I dont know how you can check for this. Are there any errors in /var/log/messages or some similar file.

Comment: What are the devices you're trying to use and what do you want to do with them ?

Comment: @meuh I was wondering that myself and I'm skimming through the USB spec at the moment to better understand the protocol from the host perspective.  I can't check the log file at the moment but i will check in an hour or so

Comment: @AndréBorie they are custom built devices that I'm not allowed to say much about (although I really don't know much about the details anyways).   My understanding is that we are just sending simple state transition commands every once in awhile

Comment: `lsusb -v` will show `Isochronous` as the Transfer Type for an Endpoint Descriptor, and the wMaxPacketSize and bInterval can be used to find the devices requirements.

Comment: @HowsItStack if no processing power is needed you could recycle old machines (that you can get for almost nothing) and have one machine per 10 USB devices. It's not a perfect solution, but it's better than having multiple unreliable daisy-chained USB hubs on a single machine.

Comment: @AndréBorie we may end up having to use multiple machines but we are currently trying not to because it would require significant software updates to synchronize everything across all the devices.  having a single machine would definitely simplify things.

Comment: @AndréBorie and HowsIt: there's usb-over-IP support in Linux, so you could use that as a workaround to avoid modifying your software.

Comment: @PeterCordes I've personally tried it on a local Ethernet network without success, so I doubt it'll be reliable or even work. Multiple machines would be better and not violate any standards (USB wasn't designed to be used over IP and it expects very low latencies)

Comment: @AndréBorie: thanks for the heads up.  updated my answer.  Clearly exporting the devices over the network with a protocol other than USB would be ideal, if HowsIt does end up needing the multiple machines workaround.  Probably a simple network protocol for exporting these custom devices to one host would be simpler than trying to make the main application distributed.

Answer (score 4):

I dealt with this problem too and it took me a while to find the real problem and solutions. It's a long page, so you can go read it there [http://marc.merlins.org/perso/linux/post_2018-12-20_Getting-Around-USB3-xhci-32-Device-Limit-*Max-number-of-devices-this-xHCI-host-supports-is-32*.html](http://marc.merlins.org/perso/linux/post_2018-12-20_Getting-Around-USB3-xhci-32-Device-Limit-_Max-number-of-devices-this-xHCI-host-supports-is-32_.html)

Basically, it boils down to these things
1) there is a 96 endpoint limit with USB3 (which translates to 32 devices only)
2) you lose further endpoints due to hubs, using a USB2 cable to a USB3 hub gives you a few slots back
3) more generally you should disable USB3 if you can do without it (remove the USB3 kernel driver, or easier if you can, disable USB3 in your bios)
4) if you cannot disable USB3, get a USB2 only PCIe card and that one will truly give you 120 devices or so.

Further resources:
https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-usb/msg175224.html
https://forums.intel.com/s/question/0D50P00004905stSAA/hardware-limitations-on-usb-endpoints-xhci?language=en_US

Comment: If my laptop has 2 usb controller, does that mean each controller has a max of 32 devices so i will have 64 devices in total?

Comment: If you have 2 independent controllers, you will indeed get 64 devices, but most computers only have one, shared across many ports. The only way I got 2 was by adding a PCI card.

Comment: same problem here. I reached the limit. usb hhub 4 points + 12 devices =16 hard limit. It is very annoying that they have not added bios setting to fix this issue so many years ago! As I understand correctly it is hard-limit by bios how much memory gives per endpoint for each usb device. This must be fixed!!!! Today we have gigabytes of memory!

Comment: solution here: https://www.systutorials.com/how-to-force-a-usb-3-0-port-to-work-in-usb-2-0-mode-in-linux/

Answer (score 3):

Many devices at once is at least supposed to work, [according to his LJ article about making a serial console remote-access server](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6518).  Limits of up to 127 USB devices (including hubs) per controller are mentioned (i.e. per pair of ports).

Maybe Linux has problems reaching that USB-imposed limit.  Probably the kernel log has something interesting to say, so hopefully you can post what you find there at some point.

If you need a workaround, you could [export the USB ports over the network](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/).  Then you could use multiple computers without modifying your software.  It's obviously not ideal, since it means more hardware, more power consumption, and more complexity.  The usbip sourceforge project looks abandoned, but there's still an Ubuntu package for it.  I guess the code made it into mainline Linux (2.6.28), and the user-space tools haven't needed updating.  See also [this askubuntu question about it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612355/share-usb-over-network).  This may or may not work well, depending on your devices and whether the drivers for them can handle the much higher latency of a network round trip.  See André Borie's reply to my comment on the question.

Using this might run into the same per-host limits on number of USB devices.  If so, that tells you it's nothing to do with the low-level drivers, and instead is a bit higher up in Linux's USB stack.

If you were using USB storage devices, you could use `nbd` to export block devices.